# Is it possible to poll a Task for completion?

Tags: c#, wpf, task, deadlock

I have a long running task and I don't want to block the UI, so I got a `DispatcherTimer` and I use it's tick event to check the task property `IsCompleted` but this causes some sort of deadlock because my application stops responding

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DateTime beginFirstPhase;
    DateTime beginSecondPhase;
    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    IEnumerable<string> collection;
    Task firstPhaseTask;
    Task secondPhaseTask;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressTxtBox.AppendText("Entering button click event handler\n");
        beginFirstPhase = DateTime.Now;

        dispatcherTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimer_Tick_FirstPhase;
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();

        progressTxtBox.AppendText("Begining First Phase now\n");

        firstPhaseTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            /*this is basically a big linq query over a huge collection of strings
            (58 thousand+ strings). the result of such query is stored in the field named
            collection, above*/), TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);
        progressTxtBox.AppendText("Awaiting First Phase completion...\n");
    }

    private void DispatcherTimer_Tick_FirstPhase(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - beginFirstPhase;
        //not even the line bellow is executed.
        statusTextBlock.Text = $"Running: {span.ToString()}";

        if (firstPhaseTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            dispatcherTimer.Stop();
            progressTxtBox.AppendText($"First Phase completed in {span.ToString()}\n");
            secondPhase();
        }
    }

    private void secondPhase()
    {
        beginSecondPhase = DateTime.Now;

        progressTxtBox.AppendText("Begining Second Phase now\n"));

        dispatcherTimer.Tick -= DispatcherTimer_Tick_FirstPhase;
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimer_Tick_SecondPhase;
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();

        int counter = 0;
        secondPhaseTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            foreach (string str in collection)
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() => progressTxtBox.AppendText($"iteration <{counter++}>\n"));
                IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string> queryResult; // = another linq query
                foreach (var tuple in queryResult)
                {
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => outputListView.Items.Add($"{tuple.Item1} {tuple.Item2} {str}"));
                }
            }
        }, TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);
    }

    private void DispatcherTimer_Tick_SecondPhase(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - beginSecondPhase;
        statusTextBlock.Text = $"Running: {span.ToString()}";
        if (secondPhaseTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            dispatcherTimer.Stop();
            progressTxtBox.AppendText($"Second Phase completed in {span.ToString()}\n");
            progressTxtBox.AppendText("Execution Complete");
        }
    }
}
```

What causes this to block? Does `Task.IsCompleted` blocks the caller's thread??
Isn't it possible to poll a Task like this at all? if not, is there another option?

Answer (score 1):

You want to "close" over the Task.Run, by using await operator. That way you get to tell user "Awaiting..." then when task completes you are on Gui thread automatically.  If you want progress reports I think this is done via the Progress class but can't remember.  Anyway this should get you close...

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    progressTxtBox.AppendText("Entering button click event handler\n");
    beginFirstPhase = DateTime.Now;

    dispatcherTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimer_Tick_FirstPhase;
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();

    progressTxtBox.AppendText("Begining First Phase now\n");
   progressTxtBox.AppendText("Awaiting First Phase completion...\n");
    firstPhaseTask =await  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        /*this is basically a big linq query over a huge collection of strings
        (58 thousand+ strings). the result of such query is stored in the field named
        collection, above*/), TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);
    progressTxtBox.AppendText("First Phase complete...\n");

}
```

I'd also suggest changing the results to be...

```
 var results =await  Task<IEnumerable<OfType>>.Factory.StartNew(() =>{
          return context.where(p=>p.field = fieldvalue);
```

Comment: This doesn't compile: `firstPhaseTask = await TaskFactor.StartNew(...)`. Also, I the second phase to start only after the first phase is complete, otherwise the objects will be in an inconsistend state. This is why I need to poll if phase one is complete or not.

Comment: No you don't need to poll if you use closures, it doesn't compile because you need to change the code to look similar to my suggestion.  If you need a result of a query, return the results as shown in suggestion.  When compiler hits an await state this thread is suspended automatically until the resumption which sets the var results.  Then you are on main thread and the same thing happens when 2nd await is hit if you have a "Closure"....

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're not using `async` and `await`?

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            /*this is basically a big linq query over a huge collection of strings
            (58 thousand+ strings). the result of such query is stored in the field named
            collection, above*/), TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);

// StartSecondPhase won't get called until the Task returned by Task.Factory.StartNew is complete
await StartSecondPhase();
```

Comment: So this means I can't periodically poll a `Task` for completion? Because second phase can't start if first phase isn't complete

Comment: You can poll but why?  There's no reason for it unless you want current progress.

Comment: @JohnPeters I also want current progress. And if I can poll, how do I do it? checking Task.IsCompleted causes a deadlock apparently.

Comment: @FinnTheHuman You might want current progress, but that makes no sense in the context of a `Task`. Your `Task` object has either "I am complete" or "I am not complete" status. So, all you need to do is `await` it. If you want some sort of progress, whatever it is that's running inside the `Task` should emit events asynchronously (through `IObservable` or `IProgress` perhaps) that you can deal with.

Comment: @moswald so why cant I ask the Task "hey, you complete yet?" every 5 seconds? Why does that cause a deadlock? Task.IsCompleted has no purpose but to block the thread that invokes it. All I want is this: a way to periodically poll a task to see if it has ended it's execution, without blocking the caller thread. I don't want to await. I want to do it like this. Is this possible? Nevermind if await is better on most situations. The question is now "how it's the best way to do this" is "is it possible to do this using that design pattern".

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to answer this. `await` doesn't block the caller thread, that's what it's for. As for `Task.IsCompleted`, that doesn't cause the calling thread to block, either. You've got a deadlock somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware I have a deadlock somewhere, but I can't figure out where and why. I have a different thread polling IsCompleted. I tried to surround the if statement with a `lock` and still got the same result. It seems to be a very misterious issue.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would approach this way:
Find a show busy animation service that you like, google is your friend.

Invoke the busy animation (Tell the user to wait, you may find one that let you update the current state as well)

run the operation like already suggested but with minimum modification like this:

```
this.BusyService.ShowBusy();
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        PhaseOne();
        PhaseTwo();
), TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);
t.ContinueWith(()=>{ this.BusyService.HideBusy(); });
```

I'm talking about a service for the showbusy because I associate it with Prism and WPF but also a simple WinForm can do the trick and there's sample example even here on SO I think.

What will happen: UI is blocked but not freezed, user will know he has to wait, on the task callback you will release the UI.

Hope this help.

EDIT:
Let's approach this a bit differently, here's a demo for WinForms of the Busy indicator I was talking about:
[BusySample](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxLb2LI1mZuPTUJEc2NSMjdZVjA)

There's a BusyForm which is just a modeless form with a multiline textbox where you're gonna write your update text.
Plus there's the main form who use it like this:

```
         private BackgroundWorker worker;
    private BusyForm busyForm = new BusyForm();
    private string progressText;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressText = "Entering button click event handler" + Environment.NewLine;
        busyForm.SetText(progressText);
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        busyForm.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        busyForm.Hide();
    }

    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        progressText += "Begining First Phase now" + Environment.NewLine;
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            busyForm.SetText(progressText);
        });
        PhaseOne();
        progressText += "First Phase complete..." + Environment.NewLine + "Begining Second Phase now" + Environment.NewLine;
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            busyForm.SetText(progressText);
        });
        PhaseTwo();
        progressText += "Execution Complete";
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            busyForm.SetText(progressText);
        });
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); //Just adding a delay to let you see this is shown
    }

    private void PhaseOne()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }

    private void PhaseTwo()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
```

BackgroundWorker is taking care of all stuff and it's running on a separate thread, anyway you need to update the text using:

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        busyForm.SetText(progressText);
    });
```

Because you need to update UI from the UI thread. I wrote the sample in like 10 minutes and I didn't tested it much but that should give you an idea.

Comment: I don't know what BusyService is. can you send me a link, please?

Comment: This suggestion uses continuations which will block until done.  Right?  Use the await keyword as suggested below.

Comment: @FinnTheHuman I updated my answer with a full working sample of what I meant for busy service. I wrote that one on the go but you can improve it or just find another on the web. Unfortunately I'm not able to give you a link or the one I use at work.

Comment: @Christopher Because this uses WindowsForms I don't know how to implement it on my WPF application.

Comment: @FinnTheHuman Are you also using prism? Anyway I'll post a wpf version when I'll have some time

Comment: @FinnTheHuman anyway if you try to replicate the sample in wpf just adding the System.ComponentModel using should make it work. Did you tried that?

Comment: I don't know what Prism is, sorry.